# C# ComboBox databinding

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a routine which opens a recordset and builds the Items collection for a combo box. After googling around I found the approach which uses the ComboboxItem class.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Display;
    }
}
```

My code uses this class to Add items to the ComboBox. When I run the app and click the Combobox the correct values are in the list... great! My problem is that when the form loads a record from the database, instead it looking up the appropriate list value which corresponds to the database value, it simply shows the value from the database: eg UK instead of United Kingdom. When I try to save the record, it tries to save "United Kingdom" instead of "UK". So I think the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties need assigning. I assumed that I would need to assign them as "Text" and "Value", but when I do this the Combobox displays a list of identical values. What am I doing wrong please?

Edit: This is a simplified version of what I have put into my ComboBox Class:

```
public class StandardComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        protected List<ComboboxItem> DataSourceList = new List<ComboboxItem>();

        public bool SetRecordSource(string Criteria)
        {
            ADODB.Recordset RS = new ADODB.Recordset();

            try
            {
                DataSourceList.Clear();

               // Open ADDOB.Recordset RS with the records specified in Criteria

               while (RS.EOF == false)
               {
            ComboboxItem MyComboboxItem = new ComboboxItem();
            MyComboboxItem.Value = RS.Fields[0].Value.ToString();
            MyComboboxItem.Display = RS.Fields[1].Value.ToString();

                    DataSourceList.Add(MyComboboxItem);

                    RS.MoveNext();
                }

                this.DataSource = DataSourceList;
                this.ValueMember = "Value";
                this.DisplayMember = "Display";

                return true;
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Is this a WPF application?

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you should name your class better (eg. Country). Then set the name of the property too. Use string as your data type.

```
public class Country
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you bind the combobox and set the DisplayMember and DisplayValue.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = listCountry;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

If you want to take the value, just use SelectedValue.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Full source code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var listCountry = new List<Country>() {
                new Country() {ID = "UK", Name = "United Kingdom"},
                new Country() {ID = "US", Name = "United States of America"},
            };

            comboBox1.DataSource = listCountry;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using a List variable. I'm adding items directly to the ComboBox Items collection. I'm doing it this way because my PopulateComboBox() routine is a generic routine which can set up the Items for any ComboBox. I can't think of a graceful way of instantiating a dynamic list which would persist after the routine terminates. I found quite a number of examples showing people adding items directly to the ComboBox items collection. I'm surprised that I'm having this problem with the behaviour afterwards.

Comment: I hit on an idea. I've overridden the ComboBox Class and given the class it's own List, then i've used your code above to populate it. I still have the same problem though..... When a record is loaded from the database, the value displayed is "UK" instead of "United Kingdom". I click on the combo box and all the proper items are there. I am using the syntax:         ComboBox.Value = RS.Fields[0].Value.ToString(); That is correct isn't it? Edit: Damn i'm thinking now that I have to do my own lookup in the list for the record that corresponds to my database value.

Comment: Please edit your post, so I can see the modification of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work this out now. I'm from an MsAccess background where for example you just assign a combobox with 'UK' and the combobox displays 'United Kingdom'. In C# it's more complicated. When you want to assign a combobox with a value, you have to use the FindString() method to locate the value you want to display, then assign the SelectedIndex property in order to make it display that value. It's a ball ache, but I can build this logic into my class and not have to think about it again. Thanks for your input. –